# Is changing interface property type a breaking change?

Tags: c#, interface

Is this a breaking interface change? If so, why? (Not a homework assignment just trying to make sure other clients aren't broken with this change)

Current interfaces:

```
public interface MyInterface
{
     IPropertyInterfaceOld Propery1 {get; set;}
}

public interface IPropertyInterfaceOld
{
}
```

Proposed interfaces:

```
public interface MyInterface
{
     IPropertyInterfaceNew  Propery1 {get; set;}
}

public interface IPropertyInterfaceOld
{
}

public interface IPropertyInterfaceNew : IPropertyInterfaceOld
{
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, that's absolutely a breaking change.

If the property is read/write, then the change breaks this code:

```cs
MyInterface x = new MyImplementation();
IPropertyInterfaceOld y = null;
x.Propery1 = y;
```

Even if the property is read-only, consider this class:

```cs
public class Implementation : MyInterface
{
    public IPropertyInterfaceOld Propery1 => null;
}
```

That implementation is broken by your change. You may have changed all the implementations in the project that *declares* the interface, but any other implementations will now be broken.

(It's *also* a binary breaking change as noted in comments.)